# Rails + Single Table Inheritance: How to customize validation error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent class:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :street_address
  validates_presence_of :street_address2
  validates_presence_of :zip_code
  validates_presence_of :city
  validates_presence_of :state_id
  validates_presence_of :phone_number

end
```

And two subclasses:

```
class ShippingAddress < Address
end


class BillingAddress < Address
end
```

However, when I'm creating invalid records on my form (I'm creating both at once), the validation errors for ShippingAddress and BillingAddress are identical, which I don't want:

```
First name can't be blank
First name can't be blank
Last name can't be blank
Last name can't be blank
Street address can't be blank
Street address can't be blank
Street address2 can't be blank
Street address2 can't be blank
Zip code can't be blank
Zip code can't be blank
City can't be blank
City can't be blank
Phone number can't be blank
Phone number can't be blank
```

How would I prefix the validation errors with the class name like `"Shipping address first name can't be blank"`?

== UPDATE ==

Yoshi's answer doesn't work when I try it:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base  
  validates_presence_of :first_name, message: I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.#{self.model_name.to_s.underscore}.attributes.first_name")




Nets-Mac-Pro:ilook emai$ be rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
irb(main):001:0> s = ShippingAddress.new
=> #<ShippingAddress id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, street_address: nil, street_address2: nil, zip_code: nil, phone_number: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, state_id: nil, city: nil, type: "ShippingAddress", order_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0> s.valid?
=> false
irb(main):003:0> s.errors.full_messages
=> ["First name translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.address.attributes.first_name", "Last name can't be blank", "Street address can't be blank", "Street address2 can't be blank", "Zip code can't be blank", "City can't be blank", "State can't be blank", "Phone number can't be blank"]
```

It says that the model name is Address instead of ShippingAddress. I'm guessing this is eager loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails uses `human_attribute_name` to convert an attribute name to a human readable form. You can try overriding this class method in `ShippingAddress` and `BillingAddress` to avoid having to specify each validation message in your locale file.

```
class ShippingAddress < Address
  def self.human_attribute_name(*args, &block)
    "Shipping address #{ super }"
  end
end

class BillingAddress < Address
  def self.human_attribute_name(*args, &block)
    "Billing address #{ super }"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I just added this to my en.yml file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      shipping_address:
        first_name: "Shipping address first name"
        last_name: "Shipping address last name"
        street_address: "Shipping address street address"
        street_address2: "Shipping address apt/suite"
        zip_code: "Shipping address zip code"
        city: "Shipping address city"
        state_id: "Shipping address state"
        phone_number: "Shipping address phone number"
      billing_address:
        first_name: "Billing address first name"
        last_name: "Billing address last name"
        street_address: "Billing address street address"
        street_address2: "Billing address apt/suite"
        zip_code: "Billing address zip code"
        city: "Billing address city"
        state_id: "Billing address state"
        phone_number: "Billing address phone number"
```